# String split for a CLOB value and insert splitted strings after a certain position as new row

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, split

I have a string in which there are several sentences seperated by ';'.
I need a solution to split the string into seperate rows and insert them into another table.

The condition to split the string should be as follows:

> The string length should accomodate atmost 699 characters and end at the nearest ';' character as that marks the end of a statement and we wont want it to end midway.

For example:If we have a string like "abcdefg;thjiksfg;a;" 
and we want our string length to be atmost 12chars 
then the resulting rows after split and processing should have values like

```
row1:abcdefg; 
row2:thjiksfg;a;
```

Please suggest how can I do it using a pl/sql procedure.

The current string is stored in a table as a CLOB value as it can accommodate as much as 7000/8000 characters.

Any help regarding this is much appreciated.

Comment: @Gordon edited the tags.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try below procedure. Inside procedure i am getting the clob data into v_text.According to your requirement you can pass the clob data as variable too to the procedure.

```
   `PROCEDURE proc_split_str --(ur_clob_data IN CLOB)
     AS
    v_text_full CLOB;
    length_of_str PLS_INTEGER:=1;
    v_text CLOB;
    v_text_temp1 CLOB;
    v_text_temp CLOB;
    position PLS_INTEGER:=1;

    BEGIN
      /*getting data from table to v_text*/
        SELECT ur_colm_clob 
          INTO v_text
          FROM ur_table;

        WHILE(length_of_str>0)LOOP


         v_text_temp1:= SUBSTR(v_text_full,1,699);

         v_text_temp:= v_text_temp1;

             v_text_full:=SUBSTR(v_text_full,LENGTH(v_text_temp1)+1,LENGTH(v_text_full)-LENGTH(v_text_temp1));

          length_of_str:=  LENGTH(v_text_full);


        WHILE (position>0) LOOP

          /*splitting clob data and stored in v_text*/
            position   :=INSTR(v_text_temp,';',1);

             IF position >0 THEN
                v_text:=SUBSTR(v_text_temp,1,position-1);
                    v_text_temp:=SUBSTR(v_text_temp,length(v_text)+2,length(v_text_temp)-length(v_text)-1);
             ELSIF position=0 THEN
                v_text      :=v_text_temp;
                v_text_temp :=null;
             END IF;

             INSERT INTO ur_new_table(ur_column)
             VALUES (v_text);


        END LOOP;

   END LOOP;

END;
/`
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I get your point anju but my main challenge is "How do I get the position of the ';' that should come before 699 characters" I dont see you having considered that value anywhere.Could you explain me how I can take that into consideration because that is the main tricky part of the requirement.

Comment: have edited the code so that entire string is splitted into small strings with characters with 699 length and then processing that string inside another loop to split with ';'.

Comment: @ anju thanks have got your point and modifying it to meet my requirement case.

Comment: @Pritha please mark my answer as useful if it meets your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I could get it working in `SQL SERVER` with following sample code, using max allowed length to be 15 for this example. (Not a great code, just to demonstrate the idea!)

The idea is
* Split the string with semi colon
* Keep concatenating the split values until they reach max allowed length
* Insert into destination table

```
Declare @sentences varchar(max) = 'hi;hey buddy;how are you;see you again;bye;';
SELECT splitdata 
INTO #TempTable 
FROM dbo.fnSplitString(@sentences,';') --function to spit string into rows

DECLARE @tempSentence VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @tempBackup VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @current VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
WHILE EXISTS (select splitdata from #TempTable)
BEGIN
    SET @tempBackup = @tempSentence;
    SET @current = (SELECT TOP 1 splitdata FROM #TempTable) + ';'
    SET @tempSentence = @tempSentence + @current;
    IF LEN(@tempSentence) > 15
    BEGIN
        --BMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Sentence = ' || @tempBackup);
        INSERT INTO dbo.MySentences VALUES(@tempBackup)
        SET @tempBackup = '';
        SET @tempSentence = @current;
    END
    DELETE TOP (1) FROM #TempTable
END
INSERT INTO dbo.MySentences VALUES(@tempSentence)
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Results:
[image]

I have no knowledge of `Oracle`, but you can try something like (fix the syntax)

```
DECLARE @tempSentence VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @tempBackup VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN --split code from > https://lalitkumarb.com/2014/12/02/split-comma-delimited-string-into-rows-in-oracle/
  FOR str IN (
        WITH DATA AS (
        SELECT 'sentence1;sentence2;sentence3;sentence4;' str FROM dual --table here
    )
    SELECT trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL)) str
    FROM DATA
    CONNECT BY instr(str, ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
  )
  LOOP
    @tempBackup = @tempSentence;
    @tempSentence = @tempSentence || str || ';';
    IF LENGTH(@tempSentence) > 699 THEN
        BMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Sentence = ' || @tempBackup);
        --insert @tempBackup to your table
        @tempBackup = '';
        @tempSentence = str || ';';
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  BMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Last Sentence = ' || @tempSentence);
  --insert @tempSentence to your table
END;
```

Comment: @ arghya thanks.will try to use this logic in oracle as the logic seems spot on